# Loop through multiple arrays and list the result dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm struggeling with this one. How can list all devices, their model and supplier from my database? The data is stored comma-separated in the fields device, model and supplier.

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $device_explode = explode(',', $row['device']);
    $model_explode = explode(',', $row['model']);
    $supplier_explode = explode(',', $row['supplier']);

    $device = array(array($device_explode[0]), //count function? How would I do that?
                    array($model_explode[0]),
                    array($supplier_explode[0])
                  );

    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Møterom</th>
            <th>Romnummer</th>
        <th>Lokasjon</th>
        <th>Antall sitteplasser</th>
        <th>Tilgjengelig utstyr</th>
        <th>Bilde av rommet</th>
        <th>Endre</th>
        <th>Slett</th>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>".$row['name']."</td>
        <td>".$row['roomnbr']."</td>
        <td>".$row['location']."</td>
        <td>".$row['seats']."</td>
        <td>".$device[0][0]."<br>".$device[1][0]."<br>".$device[2][0]."<br></td> //also count?
        <td><img src='../img/uploads/".$row['img']."' width='150px' ></td>
        <td><a href='?p=editconfroomv2&id=".$row['id']."'>Endre</a></td>
        <td><a href='./index.php?p=deleteconfroomdb&id=".$row['id']."' class='delete'>Slett</a></td>
      </tr>
      </table>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: how is your table built? like this : `id | device | model | supplier` ?

Comment: id | name | roomnbr | location | seats | img | device | model | supplier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done this way (if I understand correct your table structure). I assume, that `$device_explode`, `$model_explode` and `$supplier_explode` have equal number of elements:

```
<?php
  // Table Header
  echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Møterom</th>
        <th>Romnummer</th>
        <th>Lokasjon</th>
        <th>Antall sitteplasser</th>
        <th>Tilgjengelig utstyr</th>
        <th>Bilde av rommet</th>
        <th>Endre</th>
        <th>Slett</th>
        </tr>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $device_explode = explode(',', $row['device']);
    $model_explode = explode(',', $row['model']);
    $supplier_explode = explode(',', $row['supplier']);

    // Table rows   
    $td = '';
    $td .= 
        "<tr>
            <td>".$row['name']."</td>
            <td>".$row['roomnbr']."</td>
            <td>".$row['location']."</td>
            <td>".$row['seats']."</td>
            <td>";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($device_explode); $i++) {
        $td .=$device_explode[$i]." ".$model_explode[$i]." ".$supplier_explode[$i]."<br>";
    } 

    $td .= 
            "</td>
            <td><img src='../img/uploads/".$row['img']."' width='150px' ></td>
            <td><a href='?p=editconfroomv2&id=".$row['id']."'>Endre</a></td>
            <td><a href='./index.php?p=deleteconfroomdb&id=".$row['id']."' class='delete'>Slett</a></td>
        </tr>";
    echo $td;   
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: why `-1` there `$i < count($device_explode)-1` ?

Comment: Check how explode() returns items. Sometimes, if string finishes with ',', it return empty item. Fix this as you expect. I'll remove this from answer, because it may be confusing. Thanks!

Comment: better to fix it inside the loop rather than in the condition, what if the string is properly build and doesn't finishes with `,` ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looping trough the arrays in the markup and generating the output using the html templating syntax and alternative control structures.

Some things i have done[not related directly to the question]:

- switched the array() syntax for the shorthand [can be done since version 5.4]
- switched from using a single echo to utilizing the html templating syntax [by expluding non dynamic parts from php and echoing the dynamic parts in]
- Switched from using the echo statement to using the shorthand
- Switched to alternative control structures

[PHP documentation for strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $device_explode = explode(',', $row['device']);
    $model_explode = explode(',', $row['model']);
    $supplier_explode = explode(',', $row['supplier']);

    //I am assuming you want to loop trough all exploded fields related to each row
    $devices = [
        $device_explode,
        $model_explode,
        $supplier_explode
    ];

?>


<?php while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))) : ?>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Møterom</th>
            <th>Romnummer</th>
            <th>Lokasjon</th>
            <th>Antall sitteplasser</th>
            <th>Tilgjengelig utstyr</th>
            <th>Bilde av rommet</th>
            <th>Endre</th>
            <th>Slett</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['roomnbr'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['location'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['seats'] ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php foreach ($devices as $deviceSpecs) :  //Here we loop trough the first dimension fo the array ?>
                <?php foreach ($deviceSpecs as $deviceSpec): //Here we loop trough the second dimension ?>
                <?= $deviceSpec ?><br>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </td>
            <td><img src='../img/uploads/<?= $row['img'] ?>' width='150px' ></td>
            <td><a href='?p=editconfroomv2&id=<?= $row['id'] ?>>Endre</a></td>
            <td><a href='./index.php?p=deleteconfroomdb&id=<?= $row['id'] ?>' class='delete'>Slett</a></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I get syntax error, unexpected end of file.

Comment: You forgot a `;` there `<?php endforeach ?>`

Comment: thanks for the heads up i might have accidentally deleted it during the copy pasting. will update my answer

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I'm still getting unexpected end of file on this solution.